# How to use Swift - Autocomplete in textView

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, autocomplete, textview

I have a textView where user can add comments and mention to other users.
I've build a function which is triggered when the user type the sign "@".
So basically as in Instagram or Facebook when the user types "@" a tableview appears and show the user suggestions.
Here's my function:

```
func suggestUser() {
    if let searchText = postTextField.text {
        let words = searchText.components(separatedBy: .whitespacesAndNewlines)
        for var word in words {
            if word.hasPrefix("@") {
                word = word.trimmingCharacters(in: .punctuationCharacters)
                let userToSearch = String(word.dropFirst())
                self.viewContainerForTableView.isHidden = false
                self.suggestedUsers.removeAll()
                self.tableView.reloadData()
                Api.User.queryUsersByMentionName(WithText: userToSearch, completion: { (user) in
                    if !self.suggestedUsers.contains(where: { $0.id == user.id }) {
                        self.suggestedUsers.append(user)
                    }
                    self.tableView.reloadData()
                })
            } else {
                self.viewContainerForTableView.isHidden = true
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I have two issue:
1) When the user clicks on the suggested user in the tableview, how can i remove the text he already typed and add the one he selected?
Let me give you an example:

If a user types @jan in the tableView appears janedoe. When the user click on the suggested name in table view how can i remove jan and add janedoe?

Here's my code for the didSelectRowAt

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    let username = suggestedUsers[indexPath.row].username
    let usernameToAppend = username.components(separatedBy: .whitespacesAndNewlines).joined()
     postTextField.text.append("\(usernameToAppend)")
}
```

2) Is there a way to check if an user is already typed in the textView and so not displaying it in the tableview?

Thank you!

Comment: Does suggestUser func works when you have more than one @ character?

Comment: @Rajesh yes it does... i have implemented the delegate

Comment: Before appending selected name remove userToSearch string

Comment: @Rajesh yeah....but... i'm new to swift... and i don'y know how to remove it...

Comment: and i can't remove all the text... if i have lets say: "@jane doe have you seen @johnd..:" i need to remove just johnd to add jhondoe and not the entire textfield...

Comment: But your code checks all words for "@" character. When you are typing "@johnd" the code will show suggestion for "@jane"

Comment: no...  Api.User.queryUsersByMentionName....perform a query in firebase... and return all the user with the letter i've type..

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/159047/discussion-between-rajesh-and-marco).

Comment: @Moritz i know... didn't added it because i wasn't sure was correct.. and in fact Rajesh let me noticed a case where it doesn't work... so basically the answer is not correct...

Comment: yeah sorry... i'll edit... :)

Comment: you already did it... :) thx...

Answer (score 1):

After an entire day of trying i Think I've found a solution... Hopefully...

so I have created an extension for my textView:

```
extension UITextView {

var currentWord : String? {

    let beginning = beginningOfDocument

    if let start = position(from: beginning, offset: selectedRange.location),
        let end = position(from: start, offset: selectedRange.length) {

        let textRange = tokenizer.rangeEnclosingPosition(end, with: .word, inDirection: 1)

        if let textRange = textRange {
            return text(in: textRange)
        }
    }
    return nil
  }
}
```

Then in my didSelectRowAt i have:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    let username = suggestedUsers[indexPath.row].username
    let usernameToAppend = username.components(separatedBy: .whitespacesAndNewlines).joined()
    let currentWord = postTextField.currentWord
    if currentWord != nil && currentWord != "@"  {
        if let countIndex = currentWord?.count {
            let count = Int(countIndex)
            let startPosition = postTextField.selectedTextRange?.start
            let endPosition = postTextField.position(from: startPosition!, offset: -count)
            postTextField.selectedTextRange = postTextField.textRange(from: startPosition!, to: endPosition!)
            if let range = postTextField.selectedTextRange {
                postTextField.replace(range, withText: usernameToAppend)
            }
        }
    } else if currentWord == "@" {
        if let range = postTextField.selectedTextRange {
            if range.start == range.end {
                postTextField.replace(range, withText: usernameToAppend)
            }
        }
    }
  }
}
```